# Sorting pairs of elements from vectors to maximize a function

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector

I am working on a vector sorting algorithm for my personal particle physics studies but I am very new to coding.

Going through individual scenarios (specific vector sizes and combinations) by brute force becomes extremely chaotic for greater numbers of net vector elements, especially since this whole code will be looped up to 1e5 times.

Take four vectors of 'flavors' A and B: A+, A-, B+, and B-. I need to find two total pairs of elements such that some value k(V+, V-) is maximized with the restriction that different flavors cannot be combined! (V is just a flavor placeholder)

For example:

A+ = {a1+}
A- = {a1-}

B+ = {b1+, b2+}
B- = {b1-}

Since A+ and A- only have one element each, the value k(A+, A-) -> k(a1+, a1-). But for flavor B, there are two possible combinations.

k(b1+, b1-)  OR  k(b2+, b1-)

I would like to ensure that the combination of elements with the greater value of k is retained. As I said previously, this specific example is not TOO bad by brute force, but say B+ and B- had two elements each? The possible values would be:

k(b1+, b1-) or k(b2+,b2-) or k(b1+, b2-) or k(b2+, b1-)

where only one of these is correct. Furthermore, say two of those four B+B- combinations had greater k than that of A+A-. This would also be valid!

Any help would be appreciated!!! I can clarify if anything above is overly confusing!

I tried something like this,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

static bool sortbypair(const pair<double, double> &a, const pair<double, double> &b)
{
    return (k(a.first, a.second) > k(b.first, b.second)) && k(a.first, b.second) < k(a.second, b.first);
}
```

But I can't flesh it out.

Comment: `k` is a function?

Comment: Break down your problem into smaller pieces. First figure out how to create a collection of all combinations of `V+` and `V-`. This is called a cartesian product. Next join the cartesian products `A-`x`A+` and `B-`x`B+` into a single collection to get all viable pairs. Finally, you sort or maximize this collection over `k`, which ever you need. I suggest looking into the range-v3 library. It lets you create the needed collections without storing them in memory, so it should work for relatively large collections without a big burden on memory.

Comment: It would help, if you could provide more details: What does the function `k` do? Can you provide examples of the vectors or functions? Try to provide a minimal code example in valid C++ with all needed (but no unneeded) details.

Comment: You can probably use a greedy algorithm to solve this problem.

Start by sorting the vectors in descending order by the sum of their elements. Then, pair up the first elements of each vector, then the second elements of each vector, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who commented!!! I really appreciate your effort. The solution ended up being much simpler than I was making it out to be.

Essentially, from the physics program I'm using, the particles are given in a listed form (ie. 533  e-, 534
p+, 535  e+, etc.). I couldn't figure out how to get range-v3 working (or any external libraries for that matter but thank you for the suggestion) so I figured out to make a tuple out of the indices of combined particles and their associated k value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

static bool weirdsort(const tuple<int, int, double> &a, const tuple<int, int, double> &b)
{
    return get<2>(a) > get<2>(b);
}

int main()
{
    vector<tuple<int, int, double>> net;
// Sample ptcl list
// 
//      A+    A-    B+    B-
// 0    a1+      
// 1          a1-
// 2                      b1-
// 3                b1+
// 4    a2+
// 5          a2-
    
     
    for(int i = 0; i < A+.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < A-.size(); j++)
        {
            net.push_back(A+[i], A-[j], k(A+[i], A-[j]));
        }
    }
    sort(net.begin(), net.end(), weirdsort);
    //Now another for loop that erases a tuple (with a lower k value) if it has a repeated ptcl index.
    for (int i = 0; i < net.size(); i++)
    {
        if (get<0>(net[i]) == get<0>(net[i + 1]) || get<1>(net[i]) == get<1>(net[i + 1]))
        {
            net.erase(net.begin() + i + 1);
        }
    }
    //Now can plot third tuple element of net[0] and net[1]

    return 0;
}
```

It's not quite perfect but since I'm only looking for the first two highest k values it works out just fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly,

- you have a function `k` which maps two `double`s *(or a `std::pair<double, double>`)* to a single `double`. *I am assuming `double`, it wasn't clear from the question. It also isn't strictly at the core of your problem.*
- you have four `std::vector<double>`s: `aplus`, `aminus`, `bplus` and `bminus`.
- Your domain are all `std::pair<double, double>`s that you can form by combining the elements in `aplus` and `aminus` as well as all combinations from `bplus` and `bminus` respectively.
- you want to either

  - find the pair in your domain that maximizes `k`
  - get a collection of all pairs in your domain, sorted by the value of `k`

Did I get this right? You state in your question

> I need to find **two total pairs** of elements such that some value k(V+, V-) is maximized [...]

which confuses me a bit.

---

My suggestion is to break down your problem into three subtasks:

1. Create a range of all combinations of elements in the vectors `Vplus` and `Vminus`. This is often denoted as a cartesian product `Vplus x Vminus`.
2. Concatenate the ranges created in step 1 for `aplus x aminus` and `bplus x bminus` to get a range of **all** viable pairs in your domain.
3. Maximize/sort the range from step 2.

---

### Implementation using range-v3

The [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library provides some very convenient tools for this kind of task. Let's assume your `k` function looks like this:

```cpp
double k(double x, double y) { return x*x + y*y; }
```

and your vectors look like this:

```cpp
std::vector<double> ap{0., 4., 2., 3., 1.};
std::vector<double> am{2., -1.};

std::vector<double> bp{1., 0.5};
std::vector<double> bm{-1., 2.};
```

Let's define a range representing our domain:

```
using namespace ranges;

auto pairs_view = view::concat(
    view::cartesian_product(ap, am),
    view::cartesian_product(bp, bm)
);
```

The `pairs_view` instance doesn't actually create the pairs anywhere in memory. It is just an adaptor object that let's you iterate over all pairs that you can construct in the specified way. The pairs are created "lazily" on the fly as you - or an algorithm - iterates over it.

Let's print all pairs from our domain:

```cpp
auto print = [](auto const& p){
    auto first = std::get<0>(p);
    auto second = std::get<1>(p);
    std::cout << "[" << first << ", " << second << "] k = " << k(first, second) << std::endl;
};

for_each(pairs_view, print);
```

Output:

```
[0, 2] k = 4
[0, -1] k = 1
[4, 2] k = 20
[4, -1] k = 17
[2, 2] k = 8
[2, -1] k = 5
[3, 2] k = 13
[3, -1] k = 10
[1, 2] k = 5
[1, -1] k = 2
[1, -1] k = 2
[1, 2] k = 5
[0.5, -1] k = 1.25
[0.5, 2] k = 4.25
```

#### Finding the maximum element

Let's start by defining a convenience function *(here, in the form of a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda))* that evaluates `k` for a tuple of doubles:

```cpp
auto k_proj = [](auto const& p){
    return k(std::get<0>(p), std::get<1>(p));
};
```

You can find an iterator to the pair in your domain that maximizes `k` with just the single line:

```cpp
auto it = max_element(pairs_view, less{}, k_proj);
print(*it);
```

Output:

```
[4, 2] k = 20
```

The function `max_element` gets two additional arguments. The first is a comparison function that returns true, if two elements are in order. We provide the default `less` functor. The second argument is an optional projection that is to be applied on each element before the comparison. We pass `k_proj`.

Read the above line of code as *"Find the element in `pairs_view` of which the projection onto its `k` value is maximal, where we want to compare the projected values with the standard less function."*

#### Getting a sorted range of your domain

If you want to have all sorted range of all pairs in your domain, we must create an `std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>` for your domain first and then sort it. You cannot sort views created with the range-v3 library, because they are just a view into existing objects, they cannot be mutated. In addition, we have to map the special pair types created by the range-v3 library in the `cartesian_product` functions to actual `std::pair<double, double` to copy the values into our new container:

```cpp
auto to_std_pair = [](auto const& p){
    return std::pair<double, double>{std::get<0>(p), std::get<1>(p)};
};
auto pairs_vec = pairs_view | view::transform(to_std_pair) | to_vector;
```

Note that the "pipe" operator `|` is short-hand notation for the function composition `to_vector(view::transform(pairs_view, to_std_pair))`.

The invokation of the sorting algorithm looks very similar to the invokation of the max_element algorithm:

```cpp
sort(pairs_vec, less{}, k_proj);
```

Let's print the result:

```cpp
for_each(pairs_vec, print);
```

Output:

```
[0, -1] k = 1
[0.5, -1] k = 1.25
[1, -1] k = 2
[1, -1] k = 2
[0, 2] k = 4
[0.5, 2] k = 4.25
[2, -1] k = 5
[1, 2] k = 5
[1, 2] k = 5
[2, 2] k = 8
[3, -1] k = 10
[3, 2] k = 13
[4, -1] k = 17
[4, 2] k = 20
```

**Here is a complete live code example:** https://godbolt.org/z/6zo8oj3ah

If you don't want to use the range-v3 library you have two options:

1. You can wait. Large parts of the range-v3 library have been added to the standard library in C++20. The relevant functions `concat`, `cartesian_product` and `to_vector` will presumably be added in the upcoming standard C++23.
2. The standard library has `max_element` and `sort`. So you could just implement the concatenation and cartesian product on your own: https://godbolt.org/z/7Y5dG16WK